# MOSFET capacitance clarification

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, stability, mixed-signal

Two part question here:

1. Are there ways to directly test the input and output capacitance of a MOSFET, Ciss and Coss?
2. Due to internal inductance and capacitance, is it possible for a standalone MOSFET to resonate at certain frequencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES,YES
1) See best datasheets for test methods.

2) All traces have ESL starting at ~0.5nH/mm and scope probes are also notorious for ground ESL resonance with 10:1 coax xx pF, for resonance <50 MHz, thus tip/ring method is best between to nearby pins <1cm apart with gnd clip and probe tip both removed.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the FET fabrication method, you may find Rgate and Rsubstrate are adequate to dampen the resonances.